# Downloads at civicrm.org/download/list stopped working

Tags: upgrade

Today I tried to download the latest 4.7 version of Civicrm,
at the download page:
https://civicrm.org/download/list

I get this as message after clicking the download button:

"Not Found
The requested URL /civicrm--joomla.zip was not found on this server."

at this url None of the download links seem to work at this moment.

Did I miss something or is this a temporary error/bug?

Thank you.

Greetins,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested and they seem to work now - please try again?